# ES6 imports auto suggestion

Tags: auto-complete-mode, javascript, auto-fill-mode

I'm new to emacs and trying to setup emacs for ES6/React developement. I would like to have auto suggestions for `es6` imports like `lodash` similar to *vscode* (as shown in screenshot). Is there a way to acheive this in emacs?

[image]

Comment: I don't use such fancy features, but you might be able to get these suggestions using some LSP solution or tern.

Answer (score 1):

As DoMiNeLa10♦ metioned, lsp-mode can do this:

[image: lsp-mode]

You should install typescript-language-server in your system and lsp-mode, js2-mode, autocomplete in your emacs. You can check these link for more details.

https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode

https://emacs-china.org/t/tide-javascript/7068

Or you can check my emacs.d file:
https://github.com/RezoChiang/prelude